# Извлечь слова из аудио

Tags: аудио, поиск-программ

Есть ли программы\технологии, которые позволяют извлекать слова из аудио? Или хотя бы извлечь отрезки где встречаются слова

Comment: По моему это уже было http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632038/…. "Есть ли программы\технологии, которые позволяют извлекать слова из аудио" - есть, это CMU Sphinx, НТK, есть и другие. В исходном вопросе я дважды давал ссылку на профессиональный форум, где можно найти квалифицированную консультацию :(

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, вопросы разные. Чтобы порезать запись на слова, распознавание самих слов не требуется. Должны быть довольно значительные признаки. Скорее всего наоборот, для распознавания текста запись сначала делится на слова.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ладно убираю минус и даю еще раз ссылку на ресурс, где обитают проффи http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showforum=35, хотя вопросы об одном и том же.

Comment: @Qwertiy спс, согласен. Если ТС уточнит вопрос - то восстановлю.